# Need help jQuery nav menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

My nav menu dose not close, when a link is not clicked. I have a code pen

```
var nav = $('#menu > ul > li');
nav.find('li').hide();
nav.click(function () {
nav.not(this).find('li').hide();
$(this).find('li').slideToggle();
});
$(function() {  
$('#menu input').click(function () { 
$('#menu ul').slideToggle() 
});
});
```

https://codepen.io/lootstep/pen/WNxqvew

any ideas?

Comment: It's closed for me by default.

Comment: Are you referring to the drop downs?

Comment: @berkobienb I think so

Comment: sorry yes, the drop down.

Comment: I don't see any problem issues in your code.

Comment: I mean the user can close it if they click back on the dropdown. What functionality do you want? If they click on the document, close the dropdown?

Comment: If you take the mouse off the drop menu, the menu it stays open instead of closing.

Comment: @L0ot I just posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this event handler to your JavaScript:

```
nav.mouseleave(function () {
  $(this).find("li").hide()
});
```

`mouseleave` is an event handler in jQuery that registers when the mouse leaves an element. In this case, we're tracking when it leaves the nav bar. When it does, we find all of list items and hide them.